# How to make a shared library out of a static one with CMake

Tags: linker, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

How can I create a shared library `foo.so`out if a static one `foo.a`using CMake?

Answer (score 0):

You don't quite do `foo.so` "out of" `foo.a`. However, you should be able to just use this:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(name_of_lib SHARED src1 src2 ...)
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: But I'd like dependencies to be statically linked to foo.so

Comment: Apparantely you can do it with `ar -x libtermcap.a
gcc -shared *.o -o libtermcap.so.2` But I'd like to do that with CMake